# setTimeout and event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to create a one-time event triggered by clicking anywhere. This event is created by clicking a button. I do not want the event to trigger upon clicking the button, only any subsequent clicks anywhere (including the button).

So say I've got some html like the following:

```
<body>
  <div id="someparent">
    <div id="btn"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the following javascript (jquery):

```
$('#btn').click( function() {
  $(document).one('click', function() {
    console.log('triggered');
  });
});

$('#someparent').click(function() {
  // this must always be triggered
});
```

I want to avoid stopping event propagation, but in the above example, the event is bound to document, the event then bubbles up, and the event is triggered.

One way to fix this seems to be to wrap the event creation in a timeout:

```
$('#btn').click( function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).one('click', function() {
      console.log('triggered');
    });
  }, 1);
});

$('#someparent').click(function() {
  // this must always be triggered
});
```

Now, this works fine, but I'm wondering whether this is safe. Does some notion of order of execution guarantee that this will always work, or is it just working by chance? I know there are other solutions (another nested `.one()` event for instance), but I'm specifically looking for an answer to how setTimeout and event propagation interoperates.

The following fiddle shows two divs. The first one has the wrong behaviour (the document event is triggered immediately). Clicking the second div, and then anywhere on document (white area) illustrates the wanted behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwocuuf8/7/

Comment: Can't you wire up the click event and simply remove the handle once the event has been triggered (unless the source is the button)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: just return false to prevent bubbling

Comment: I specifically want to avoid cancelling event propagation. The button could potentially have parents that wants to listen in on the click event. It's a contrived example in my question.

Comment: wow, then maybe the issue here is the way you want to implement it... why you want to bind an event without handling the bubble?

Comment: The more I read this the more I'm confused about what you want to achieve. So you click *'x'* and then this registers an event on the document. Why? and why don't you want to prevent propagation?

Comment: if you want to bubble everything then just stay with `$(document).on('click')` although I would not recommend it

Comment: Techunter: I added a fiddle. but it seems Andrea Casaccia already provided an answer.

Comment: ok I understand the question better now lol. working with setTimeout never guarentee the order and should never be used to solve issue like this. Casaccia has the correct answer

Comment: Andrea Casaccia's answer says the order IS guaranteed.

Comment: btw your code says `.one('click')` instead of `.on('click')` in several spots.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Event bubbling means that, after an event triggers on the deepest possible element, it then triggers on parents in nesting order.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Adding_messages

> **Adding messages**
>
> In web browsers, messages are added any time an event occurs and there
>   is an event listener attached to it. If there is no listener, the
>   event is lost. So a click on an element with a click event handler
>   will add a message--likewise with any other event.
>
> Calling setTimeout will add a message to the queue after the time
>   passed as second argument. If there is no other message in the queue,
>   the message is processed right away; however, if there are messages,
>   the setTimeout message will have to wait for other messages to be
>   processed. For that reason the second argument indicates a minimum
>   time and not a guaranteed time.

So, the behaviour you have, is not by chance, you are guaranteed that the messages in the queue will be processed *before* processing the message you add after a timeout.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This guarantees the expected behaviour. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of what you want: after clicking an "activation" button, the next click anywhere on the page (including on the "activation" button) should trigger a special event. This is easily handled with a flag:

```
var activationFlag = false;

$('#btn').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  if(!activationFlag) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Global event activated');
  }

  activationFlag = true;
});

$('#someparent').click(function(event){
  if(activationFlag) {
    console.log('Time for a special event');
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a contrived example constructed from a real world problem, so it looks a little weird. There are numerous better solutions than the `setTimeout` approach I used, but I was specifically looking for an answer to whether the expected behaviour was guaranteed. I do however agree that a flag is the appropriate solution in this case, although I would avoid stopping event propagation as you do in your example.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/jqrgn1rh/2/) by using a flag instead of a second event :

```
var documentWaitingClick = false;
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (documentWaitingClick) {
      //simulate the "one"
      documentWaitingClick = false;
      console.log('document click');
    } else if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      documentWaitingClick = true;
      console.log('button click')
    }
  });
});
```